# Correct use of subprocess in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 pdf files to convert into text everyday via terminal, pdftotext module, and from there sort the data with a python script. To save time typing in,`for file in *.pdf; do pdftotext -layout "$file"; done` into the terminal, I thought I could add it to the top of the following .py script.
I believe subprocess is the answer, but for the life of me I am unable to get it to save a .txt file beside the .pdf the same as pdftotext does via the terminal.
I have tried "Quotes", [Lists] and "Quotes" in [Lists], even tried "usr/lib/pdftotext".
Why does this not work for a pdf in home folder,

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['pdftotext', '-layout', 'ALL.pdf', 'ALL.txt'])
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens? Do you get any errors? Do you do `process.wait()` to wait for the program to finish? Is `process.returncode()` 0? You could use `subprocess.check_output(...)` , it will raise an error if the program returns a nonzero return code.

Comment: This should work as long as you are in the directory with the pdf. You should wait for the process to complete (or use subprocess.call or subprocess.check_call) before exiting but that won't cause the call to fail. I created a pdf and ran your exact code and it worked for me. I cannot duplicate this.

Comment: I'm voting to close as cannot reproduce. If you have more information, then we can reopen and look at it.

Comment: Nothing happens, no .txt file. I just tried process.wait() and still nothing.

Comment: Rescinding close. How are you executing this script? I've been assuming its from the command line. Linux, Windows... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the answer but how to get to the answer. When programs don't behave, start testing your assumptions and printing information as you go. This example should reduce the possible problems. You should see some prints from this program. If not, it may have to do with *how* you run the program. I am assuming that you run from the command line where you can see standard and error prints from python and `pdftotext`. If not, this will need updates.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import os
import sys
import time

# just in case we are double clicking from a windows manager and the
# window doesn't stay up very long
print "Starting in..."
for i in range(3, 0, -1):
    print i
    time.sleep(1)

# if you don't see these, it may be how you are running the program.
print "Platform", sys.platform
print "Running in directory", os.getcwd()

if not os.path.isfile('ALL.pdf'):
    print >> sys.stderr, "ALL.pdf does not exist"
    exit(2)

if os.path.isfile("ALL.txt"):
    print "Found old ALL.txt, deleting"
    os.remove("ALL.txt")

print "Running pdftotext..."

subprocess.check_output(['pdftotext', '-layout', 'ALL.pdf', 'ALL.txt'])
if not os.path.isfile('ALL.txt'):
    print "Program did not create ALL.txt"
    exit(2)
print "Success! ALL.txt was written."

# note: if you don't see "Success!" something bad happened
```

I created a test file and ran it

```
td@mintyfresh ~/tmp $ python test.py
Starting in...
3
2
1
Platform linux2
Running in directory /home/td/tmp
Found old ALL.txt, deleting
Running pdftotext...
Success! ALL.txt was written.
```

I then injected a file-not-found error and ran again

```
td@mintyfresh ~/tmp $ mv ALL.pdf ALL.pdf-tmp
td@mintyfresh ~/tmp $ python test.py
Starting in...
3
2
1
Platform linux2
Running in directory /home/td/tmp
ALL.pdf does not exist
```

It detected one obvious problem easily.

Comment: It is the answer though, made the .txt file as required. My example used Popen, which did nothing, and when I changed my code to check_output, it worked also.

Comment: Any ideas on how to loop over 2 pdf's and instead of having ALL.pdf as a name but a variable name that includes the days date in the title, eg. ALL_30_03_2017.pdf and ALL_31_03_2017. I tried a variable name but the error said it had to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you should do, for more info check subprocess documentation

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

```
import os, subprocess

process = subprocess.call('pdftotext -layout ALL.pdf ALL.txt', shell=True, cwd=os.path.expanduser('~'))
```

Comment: "Why does this not work for a pdf in home folder"
this is in the question

Comment: If OP wasn't in the home directory at the time, he would have gotten an error from pdftotext. I'm still not convinced this will solve the problem. We'll have to wait to see what OP says!

Comment: pdftotext should be in one of the paths in the $PATH env var, if not then OP have to put an absolute path of pdftotext, not a big deal...

Comment: I am very basic with python and $PATH var is unknown to me, and if the absolute path is "/usr/bin/pdftotext", tried that too.

Comment: @Albert did you get an error? can you please share it?